# Prevent submitting form in Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, form-submit

I have a form with

```
<form id=myform onsubmit=return validate();>
<input type=text id=name name=name>
</form>
```

In my javascript file I have

```
function validate(){
 $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: app.url.prefix,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {service: 'manage', met: 1, name: name },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.exists){
                 return false;
            }

        }

    });
return true;
}
```

This `Ajax` code check if the returned data has value especially the `data.exists`. I would like to prevent submit form based on the value of exists.

This
`if (data.exists){
    return false;
}`

does not really work.

Comment: To be 100% sure. You wanna prevent the form from reloading the page if you're pressing enter while the input is active ?

Comment: The problem is, ajax means async operation. So you should prevent the submit and on positive feedback you should submit the form in your success function.

Comment: I want IF  data.exists == (what I dont want) THEN dont submit. but I have return true at the end of the function and because AJAX is asynchronous it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

This should do the trick, now the form won't reload the page on pressing enter or a button.

EDIT:
Your form is also missing double-quotes

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs because of async ajax function call, it returns true before ajax data returns.
I haven't checked it, But you can try something like this:

```
function validate(){
var self = this;
self.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: app.url.prefix,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {service: 'manage', met: 1, name: name },
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.exists){
                 self.submit();
            }

        }

    });
```

return false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I have changed my `HTML` and I have added `onclick` event than `onsubmit`

```
<form id="myform">
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
   <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="validate();">
</form>
```

Also in `Javascript`

I prevent the submit here

```
 $("#button").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is my function to check if not exists data so then submit form

```
function validate(){

$.ajax({

 dataType: 'json',
 url: app.url.prefix,
 method: 'POST',
 data: {service: 'manage', met: 1, name: name },
 success: function (data) {
 if (!data.exists){
   $('#myform').submit();
}
 }
  });
```